# Replace the content in RichTextEditor

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a beginner in Visual Studio and have a question related to replacement content in RichTextEditor. I have a RichTextEditor want to replace the content in between begin{document} and end{document} using c# dot net is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RichTextEditor is named `RichTextEditor1` or something like that, use this line:

```
RichTextEditor1.text = "your text here";
```

Keep in mind, it may not be `.text`, it might be either `.text`, `.Text`, `.value`, or `.Value`. Experiment with your `RichTextEditor`'s attributes, read their descriptions, and see what they do.

If you're new to programming altogether, don't start with C#.Net, start with Visual Basic and Visual Studio 2013. It's much simpler and you'll have an easier time, plus, there are books you can read to learn it.